# RecyclerView only display last item

Tags: android, android-edittext, sharedpreferences, android-recyclerview

I want to display all the users' input on the recyclerview, however, it only shows the last user's input. I don't know where I did wrong. Thank you

This is the Class where I get users' input

```
public class addEvent extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button addEventButton;

public void events(View view){

    Intent intent1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), events.class);
    startActivity(intent1);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_event);

    addEventButton = findViewById(R.id.addEventButton);
    addEventButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            EditText timeEditText = findViewById(R.id.timeEditText);
            EditText descriptionEditText = findViewById(R.id.descriptionEditText);


            final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("sharedPreferences", MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
            editor.putString("time", timeEditText.getText().toString());
            editor.putString("description", descriptionEditText.getText().toString());
            editor.apply();

        }
    });

  }
}
```

This is View Class

```
public class events extends AppCompatActivity {

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
private List<ListItem> listItems;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_events);

    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewID);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("sharedPreferences", MODE_PRIVATE);
    String timeInfo = sharedPreferences.getString("time", null);
    String descriptionInfo = sharedPreferences.getString("description", null);

    listItems = new ArrayList<>();

    ListItem item = new ListItem(timeInfo, descriptionInfo);

    listItems.add(item);

     TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        }
    };

    adapter = new MyAdapter(this, listItems);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        }
}
```

This is Model Class

```
public class ListItem {

private String time;
private String description;

public ListItem(String time, String description) {

    this.time = time;
    this.description = description;
}

public String getTime() {
    return time;
}

public void setTime(String time) {
    this.time = time;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

}
```

This is Adapter Class

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private Context context;
private List<ListItem> listitem;

public MyAdapter(Context context, List listitems){

    this.context = context;
    this.listitem = listitems;

}


@NonNull
@Override
public MyAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_row, viewGroup, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {

    ListItem item = listitem.get(i);
    viewHolder.time.setText(item.getTime());
    viewHolder.description.setText(item.getDescription());

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return listitem.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView time;
    public TextView description;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        time = itemView.findViewById(R.id.time);
        description = itemView.findViewById(R.id.description);
    }
}
}
```

Maybe I need to add a For Loop into `arrayList` so it can display all the items? And if so, how can I add it.

Comment: in your `listItems` add single item only that's why its showing one row.

Comment: What do you mean by "all users" where are you storing the users list

Comment: add more data using loop,  for now its display one record because added only one record(From your code  listItems.add(item);)

Answer (score 1):

`listItems.add(item)` only adds *a* single item.

Your `Adapter` actually works, it's just that you only add one item to it ^^

Comment: How can I add more items to it, should I use For Loop? And how can I do that?

Comment: That's another question, yet a basic one. I just described what was wrong. Yes, you could use a loop but I don't know much else about what you're trying to do with the code you shown. As of now, you're only adding one element: `ListItem item = new ListItem(timeInfo, descriptionInfo)` and that was your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is when you try to create a new event and the data is stored in `sharedPrefernce`. In your way, only the last item is stored. And when data is retrieved you have only one data (the last one). If you want to show all the data in a list then you have to use DB (for saving data) and then retrieved data from DB and show.

Or

You can try this [Tiny DB](https://github.com/kcochibili/TinyDB--Android-Shared-Preferences-Turbo) library. It's very simple.

```
TinyDB tinydb = new TinyDB(context);
```

to put

```
tinydb.putList("MyUsers", mUsersArray);
```

to get

```
tinydb.getList("MyUsers");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your are adding only one item on list. If you want multiple items on recyclerview so paste this line 5 times like this:

```
listItems.add(item);
listItems.add(item);
listItems.add(item);
listItems.add(item);
listItems.add(item);
```

this will show 5 same items list.

Answer (score 0):

As onCreate() method will get called **only once** when loading the your Activity/Fragment...
and inside your onCreate() method ....you called listItems.add(items) {Thus it will also get called once, thus showing one item from the shared prefereces}

your question : it only shows the last user's input.
As you give input in edit-text afterwards and click button then, your last inputs will get replaced by latest inputs(Why? key-value pair  i.e you modified the value for the existing key). And next time when your RecyclerView's Activity opens ..it will load last updated inputs.

Now how you can show all items:

(if your requirement is: after reopening the app all previous items should be there)

->Either maintain separate keys in Shared preferences for different inputs, then try to retrieve all into arraylist.(I do not like that)
->Use SQLite for storing and then retrieve back to arraylist.

Maintain arraylist every time with all the elements

Answer (score -1):

Its because ur arraylist creating newly everytime.